# jQuery + Animate.css animation only working once, animation not resetting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to reproduce a specific animation each time a button is pressed.

Specifically, I'm using `jQuery` and the `animate.css` library for this effect: on button click, a class is added (two classes to be precise: `fadeInDown animated`) to the element I want to animate.

The animation does work correctly, but only once. Why is this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jqm4vjLj/2/

I want the animation to reset every time I click the button, even if it is halfway through completion from a previous click. It should also work whenever I click the button, not only once.

JS:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#button").removeClass();
    $("#button").addClass("fadeInDown animated");
});
```

Classes from animate.css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/, which discusses this exact problem.

I think the cleanest solution is to wrap the functionality of removing the element and re-inserting it in the same position in the HTML tree in a global function. Then, when you want to restart an animation, you just remove the class, call the reset function (grabbing the newly-inserted element from the return value), and then add the animation class(es) back to start the animation again.

For example:

```
function reset($elem) {
    $elem.before($elem.clone(true));
    var $newElem = $elem.prev();
    $elem.remove();
    return $newElem;
} // end reset()

$("#button").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass();
    $this = reset($this);
    $this.addClass("fadeInDown animated");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jqm4vjLj/6/

This solution provides maximum responsiveness, since the old in-progress animation is automatically ended when the animating element is destroyed, and the newly-inserted element's animation begins immediately.

Comment: This is brilliant. Great answers in this thread but this piece of code absolutely nailed what I was asking for. Thank you.

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but got beat! None of the other answers  are correct, because they all wait for the animation to complete, when @Tiago said that it should restart even when it's not done.

Comment: @blex Entirely correct. I'm really happy to find such a precise solution. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 11):

A much safer approach will be use the animation end event like

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#button").addClass("fadeInDown animated").one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function() {
    $("#button").removeClass();
  });
});
```

```css
#button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.fadeInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to be what I was looking for. Would you be so kind as to explain why the duplicate .removeClass() method, before and after the animation?

Comment: @Tiago forgot to remove it... not required

Comment: Thank you @Arun for your great answer but I decided to go with bgoldst's suggestion. It does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This feels like a much cleaner solution than cloning the whole element

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution for me is to start reflow process before adding class.
You can do it for example by "change" width of element. I think reflow process is faster for browser then node reinserting. And its simpler in terms of coding.
In jQuery:

```
$(this)
  .removeClass('myAnimation')
  .width('auto') // the magic
  .addClass('myAnimation')
```

Comment: I have a custom width. So what I did was hide then show

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove class after the animation is complete,

but directly using `removeClass` wont work, because it will not let animation complete, instead use `setTimeout`

see this http://jsfiddle.net/jqm4vjLj/4/

```
   $("#button").click(function () {

        $("#button").addClass("fadeInDown animated");
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#button").removeClass("fadeInDown animated");},100)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is it immediately remove class and then add class so I just added new div with button2 id and on its click it just remove class and then click again on button div it would animate.

so problem is you need to do it after completion of animation.

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $("#button").removeClass();
});
```

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jqm4vjLj/5/

Comment: Interesting. However this doesn't fit my requirements. Having the user reset the animation won't work. Are you saying that what I need to do is set a timeout to allow for the animation to complete before removing the classes?

Comment: @Tiago Yes my intention was so but you should accept Arun's answer he is awesome. Great answer...!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is good solution for your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2c16fk7/3/

In your javascript the classes `.animation` and `.fadeInDown` were added to the `#button` and after that you had these classes and you couldn't add it again.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, from the animate.css github:

```
animateCss: function (animationName) {
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset the element we have to make css recalculate right ? So what I did was hide and then show the element. What I did was **removeClass()** and then **hide()** and then **show()** and **addClass()**

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#button").removeClass("fadeInDown animated").hide();
    $("#button").show().addClass("fadeInDown animated");
});
```