# on click animation implemented with addClass inside a setTimeOut occurs only oinceWhat

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What i have is some html at the top of the page like this:

```
<div class="candidate-details">
  <p class="name">Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p class="occupation">Lorem Ipsum Developer</p>
  <p class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> lorem.lololol@gmail.com</p>
  <div class="social-media">
    <a class="social-icon" href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><i id="gitid" class="fa fa-github fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    <a class="social-icon" href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><i id="linkedid" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the page, i have a link :

```
<p id="thank-you" class="about-contents">Thanks for stopping by. <a class="touch" href="#">Get in touch :) </a>
```

JS code:

```
  $(".touch").on("click", function(){
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
  $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".fa-envelope, .fa-github, .fa-linkedin").addClass("swing").one(animationEnd, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("swing");
    });
   }, 1500);
  });
```

and finally some CSS:

```
 .swing {
  -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.99, 0, 0.57, 0.94);
  -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.99, 0, 0.57, 0.94);
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.99, 0, 0.57, 0.94);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.99, 0, 0.57, 0.94);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Full code: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/ammoPq)

**So do i want to achieve?**

What i want is when the user clicks on the link `Get in touch` at the bottom of the page,some smooth scrolling business ensues, the user is taken to the top of the page and the three fontawesome icons rotate 360 deg getting their attention. **I want this to happen with every click.**

**What's currently happening?**

the smooth scroll happens successfully everytime. The rotation animation occurs successfully on the first click but that's it. **It doesn't repeat on every subsequent click.**

There are numerous questions on SO on CSS animation working only once but none of them have seemed to help me. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580947/jquery-animate-css-animation-only-working-once-animation-not-resetting) has come close but didn't really solve anything.

**What do i want to happen?**
The rotation animation in addition to the smooth scroll to repeat everytime the user clicks on the `Get in touch` link.

Thank you.

Comment: Once it's rotated 360 degrees, it's rotated, you don't seem to reset it back, so it won't rotate again?

Comment: Doesn't removeClass acheive that?

Comment: Use one event listener created within page load code then just add the class inside setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using animation instead of transition. Change this:

```
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
```

to

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionend';
```

Comment: ahh! simple and perfect. Thanks.